# SQL: Generating a row version for a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering if there is any possibility of generating a unique row version for a view that I am trying to create. When we have a table that consists of Rowversion column (timestamp datatype) and when we insert records into this table (without even specifying the rowversion in the insert), the rowversion is automatically generated and inserted along with the records that we have inserted. I was wondering if we can dynamically generate unique row version for each row inside the view.

My view:

```
CREATE View v_Customers
AS
    Select 
        [Id]
        ,[ChangedBy]
        ,[ChangedDate]
        ,[EnteredDate]
        , CAST(ChangedDate as timestamp) as [Rowversion]
    FROM
        AFW_Customer
Go
```

What I have tried:

- `CAST(ChangedDate as timestamp) as [Rowversion]`
- `CAST(GETDATE() as timestamp) as [Rowversion]`

But these are not generating the unique rowversion for every record inside the view. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your processes insert or update more than one row at a time into `AFW_Customer` then you won't be able to use `ChangedDate` as a unique identifier.  What is `Id` and why can't you use that as the identifier?

Comment: Can you add some background on what you are doing because it sounds like you are trying to solve a problem that might be solved in a better way

Comment: _Rowversion column (timestamp datatype)_ Stop there. TIMESTAMP is a deprecated datatype and is now just a synonym for ROWVERSION. **NO ONE** should be using TIMESTAMP in current development.

Comment: It makes no sense for a view to have a `rowversion` by itself, as it doesn't exist in a physical sense. Can you not just pass through a `rowversion` column from the base table? By the way `rowversion` aka `timestamp` is not a date.